# De Gruyter and De Gruyter Mouton: the difference

Tags: citations, publishers

What is the difference between the publisher "De Gruyter" and the publisher "De Gruyter Mouton"?

It seems that the main publishing company name is "De Gruyter", and it has an imprint which is "De Gruyter Mouton".

In the references, it is sometimes "De Gruyter" that is noted, sometimes "De Gruyter Mouton".

I search randomly two examples, reproduced here:

> Chan, W. M., Chin, K. N., Nagami, M., & Suthiwan, T. (Eds.). (2011). *Media in foreign language teaching and learning*. Boston: De Gruyter Mouton.
>
> Fornasier, M. (Ed.). (2010). *Theoretical foundations and numerical
> methods for sparse recovery* (Vol. 1). Berlin: de Gruyter.

So what is the difference, and is it significative?

To put it bluntly, can I remove "Mouton" directly when it appears in a reference of my bibliography?

Comment: Your references should include whatever information your source actually has.

Comment: _De Gruyter Mouton_ publishes in the "field of linguistics and communication science", according to https://www.degruyter.com/publishing/services/for-book-authors/our-subject-areas/linguistics-mouton?lang=en

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you've answered your own question in your second sentence - there is a large publisher called "De Gruyter", which has an imprint called "De Gruyter Mouton" ([among other imprints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Gruyter)). The reason why your two references specify different publishers is simply that they were published by different imprints - one by the parent De Gruyter, and one by the De Gruyter Mouton imprint.

It would be usual practice to refer to the actual publishing imprint, rather than the parent publisher, so I don't think it would be typical to remove the 'Mouton' from a reference as it removes actual information.